# Problems with GNU Boot Manager with Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gnu

Hello lovely Ubuntu Community!
I am having a problem with booting up Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. I have installed Ubuntu 20.4 LTS on a HP Pavilion 15. **I did make a partition.** I moved the USB stick upwards in the BIOS, and then went through the installation process. 
It told me to remove the medium of installation, which I did. **Then the screen went black for about 5 minutes and then brought me back to Windows 10.**
**I believe the main problem might be with Windows Boot Manager, because when I was selecting how to install Ubuntu, I chose to install it alongside Windows Boot Manager.**
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Can you open the boot menu of your system ? (via F12 or so ) . If so , select ubuntu from the list and after booting into the linux run "sudo update-grub" or "sudo grub-install your_device_name(e.g /dev/sda) "

Comment: This resolves my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the boot menu of your system via <kbd>F12</kbd>(might differ for different motherboards). Then select `Ubuntu` , and if it's not there, that means you haven't installed Grub2 at all. You have to either re-install the OS or just with a live ISO run `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` (if you want to install it in the first disk).

But if you have that option and you're able to boot , you can run

```
sudo update-grub
```

to make the grub2 the default bootloader of your disk. Reboot and you'll be able to boot either Windows or Ubuntu via the Grub menu.